# Falion won't help me cure my vampirism

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Trying to cure my vampirism, after loading a save AGES ago, and doing the quest to cure it. I get to Falions house, and it's locked.

(These events in this paragraph happened the first time) I tried getting in (successfully) into Falions house and of course, he wants me out. After being able to persuade the guard to let me go, being the Thane, I was able to properly talk to him and buy the gem. The problem was, everyone tried to kill me and I was too weak with the disease.

(Second time) Tried to break in, unsuccessful. Couldn't make him talk to me this time.

How do you properly talk to him? I tried waiting, didn't work.

Comment: You should be able to enter his house without picking the lock after 6pm, at which you point you can talk to him. http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Rising_at_Dawn

Comment: You could also become a werewolf. The only negative side is not receiving sleeping bonuses.

Answer (score 3):

Well, i wouldn't help someone either who broke into my house in the night.

For everyone encountering a similar problem: Wait until he is in his shop in the middle of the village. There you can talk safely to him. Alternatively, you can always speak to him in the evening, when he is near the stone circle north east from the village.

Answer (score 3):

Note: For Falion to accept to help you, you need to be non-blood starved if Dawnguard is not installed. Once you get the gem, soul trap a HUMAN only and kill him/her to get a filled black soul gem. If these conditions are met, he will tell you to come to a sacrificial alter place at dawn. Go there and he will talk gibber about souls and BAM you are human again(beast maybe)

Answer (score 1):

Is your eyes a weird color? If so, try drinking the blood of a sleeping npc or use seduction. Use seduction on a bandit. Go back to Falion with a full black soul gem and he will help you.